# Regex expression to replace different values based on multiple criterias

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-group, regex-greedy, regexp-replace

I am trying to find a REGEX expression (or multiple ones) that i can use in Notepad++ (Windows) that will change different parts of URLs based on specific symbols that divide them.

Basically i have this type of URLs in a big file, they are scaterred around:

```
domain.com/folder/random-text-1?REPLACE-THIS-1=REPLACE-THIS-2=REPLACE-THIS-3&REPLACE-THIS-4
```

The REPLACE-THIS-1/-2/-3/-4 always differs from each other, even between different URLs, like this:

```
domain.com/folder/random-text-2?A1=A2=A3&A4
domain.com/folder/random-text-2?B1=B2=B3&B4
etc
```

(Note: "folder" stays the same all the time)

This is what I am trying to do with REGEX expression(s):

- "REPLACE-THIS-1" with "REPLACED-1"
  Note: so basically when it finds the first "?" it will replace the "REPLACE-THIS-1" after it with a specific one "REPLACED-1" up to it gets to "=" symbol
- "REPLACE-THIS-2" with "REPLACED-2"
  Note: this one is between first "=" found, and second "=" found
- "REPLACE-THIS-3" with "REPLACED-3"
  Note: this is the text after second "=" found
- "REPLACE-THIS-4" with "REPLACED-4"
  Note: the problem is that  "REPLACE-THIS-4" includes sometimes the "=" symbol as well, but i want to replace all of the text after the "REPLACE-THIS-3&"

Note: REPLACED-1/REPLACED-2/REPLACED-3/REPLACED-4 are always the same, they don't change

The biggest problem i am facing is that all these replace-1/-2-/3/-4 are different amongst each other (i mean the all URLs have different values), so it'd be great if i can use a regex/multiple regex formulas to replace!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This regex should do what you want. It looks for a URL that contains `/folder/` followed by some random text, a `?` and then something of the form `a=b=c&d` where `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` may contain any non-blank characters (other than `=` for `a` and `b`, and `&` for `c`).

```
(\/folder\/[^?]+\?)[^=\s]+=[^=\s]+=[^&\s]+&.*(?=\s|$)
```

This is replaced with

```
\1REPLACE-1=REPLACE-2=REPLACE-3&REPLACE-4
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/axTbhL/2)

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
^(.*\/folder\/[A-Za-z0-9-]*\?)\D+\d+=\D+\d+=\D+\d+&\D+\d+$
```

with a replacement of,

```
$1REPLACED-1=REPLACED-2=REPLACED-3&REPLACED-4
```

might also work.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Utgx8g/1). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Utgx8g/1debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: thank you soooo much! it works as well! really appreciate it! you guys have no idea how much work this saved me!

if i could, i would upvote both as the good answer, as both work!